# Turn off an element based on text existing in an unrelated element on page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, text, find

I need to turn off a specific DIV on a page based on the appearance of some specific text that will (or will not) be sitting inside a  tag elsewhere on the page...

In the simplified case below, if the text 'Specific-Text' is found in the  element, I want to turn off the div with the class 'dependent'

```
<div>
  <table class="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>Specific-Text To Test For</ul>
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
... Lots of other stuff going on ...
<div class="dependent">
  Here's the DIV I want to show or not show based on appearance of the text 'Specific-Text'
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var specificText = "";
if ($('table.mytable *:contains("' + specificText + '")').length > 0)
   $('div.dependent').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

just take the text of the element you're searching and set `.style.display` on the dependent div:

```
document.getElementById('dependent').style.display = document.getElementById('myTable').innerText.indexOf('Specific-Text') >= 0 ? 'none' : 'block';
```